# Are stories from classic literature on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about "A Christmas Carol" by Charles Dickens.  On one hand this story seems to clearly be a fantasy story, what with the ghosts and time travel and all.  But on the other hand we do not have a `literature` tag and I do not recall having seen past questions dealing with classic literature.

My question is mainly about "A Christmas Carol" but I am also interested in the general policy toward other books of classic literature (e.g., Frankenstein, A Picture of Dorian Gray, Metamorphosis, etc...)?

Comment: I would argue any questions about Poe's work or Verne's work or Wells' work would be on topic, and they're of a similar vintage as Dickens.

Answer (score 10):

We've got "My Little Pony" questions that are considered on-topic, so it isn't like we're trying to maintain some kind of high bar for what works are allowed.

I say go for it and I'll be happy to throw in with you if someone votes to close.

Comment: Definitely! Any of the works mentioned fit our criteria for fantasy/sci-fi elements, and the fact that they are considered "classics" should *encourage* us to handle questions about them.

Comment: Well, there is the whole Brony thing going on.  MLP's popularity went crazy.  I think the [Mickey Mouse Clubhouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey_Mouse_Clubhouse) question [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24077/how-does-mickey-mouses-upslide-work) is more indicative  ;)

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  I've asked questions on *MacBeth* and a few others.  It's on topic.